# How to convert from bytearray/bytes?

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm hashing with uhashlib in MicroPython on a Raspberry Pi Pico:

```
import sys
import os
import uhashlib
import time

time_now = "blergh"
hash_test = uhashlib.sha256(time_now).digest()

print(time_now)
print(hash_test)
```

This outputs:

```
blergh
b'Y|\x84W\xa1\x1d\x86cb~\x0bL\x1e\\\x92\xcd-\x93\x05\xddz\x0e\xe1\x9f\x9a\xc1H6\x93\xd8\x0c8'
```

which isn't useful. How to convert from bytes (`b'...'`) in MicroPython?

Comment: what is your question? also you may want [`.hexdigest()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#simple-hashing)

Comment: hexdigest is what I would use for hashlib (python), but uhashlib (micropython) doesn't support it. The question is exactly what you understood, though, I'm getting bytecode when I want a hexdigest.

Comment: I've also tried ubinascii.hexlify(hash.digest()) , but no dice there - I'm wondering if this is simply broken in micropython right now?

Comment: Note that "bytecode" is not an appropriate term to use here.  Yes, it's made of bytes, and yes, you could refer to it as a code - but that term is used to refer to bytes that can be executed by some interpreted language, whereas what you have here is purely data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ubinascii.hexlify` and jump through hoops.

`ubinascii.hexlify()` returns `bytes`. By decoding the `bytes` to a `str` and then converting that `str` to an `int` (with base16), we can then pass the value to `hex()`. There is no `hex` attribute for `bytes` in micropython.

The below has been fully tested on the Raspberry Pi Pico running micropython 1.14. I suspect earlier versions would also work, as long as they possess both of the module dependencies.

```py
import ubinascii, uhashlib

hs = uhashlib.sha256(b'blergh')

def hexdigest(sha):
    return hex(int(ubinascii.hexlify(sha.digest()).decode(), 16))

hx = hexdigest(hs) #0x597c8457a11d8663627e0b4c1e5c92cd2d9305dd7a0ee19f9ac1483693d80c38
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to directly decode any bytes to hex with the `.hex()` method on it!

```py
>>> b"blerg".hex()
'626c657267'
```

I don't have `uhashlib`, but this works with the stock `hashlib`!

```py
>>> hashlib.sha256(b"blergh").digest().hex()
'597c8457a11d8663627e0b4c1e5c92cd2d9305dd7a0ee19f9ac1483693d80c38'
>>> hashlib.sha256(b"blergh").hexdigest()
'597c8457a11d8663627e0b4c1e5c92cd2d9305dd7a0ee19f9ac1483693d80c38'
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do in standard Python, but this doesn't run on micropython / pi pico.

Answer (score 0):

this mpython script has a code block that converts bytearray into decimal ascii How do you import that library if it's offline? I mean what is that library do specifically? Is there anyway you can put that in longhand?
it took many months of diligence To discover how to translate these libraries into longhand. But I can assure you that they have absolutely no external commands that must be imported or downloaded from any repository or library. I'm kinda proud of it.
[https://wokwi.com/projects/376341312102027265][https://wokwi.com/projects/376341312102027265]

```
puter=bytearray(1)
while 1:
  k=machine.Pin(28).value()
  if (k>b):
    k1=k1+1-4*(k1>3)
  b=k
  k2=machine.Pin(27).value()
  if (k2>b2):
    k1=k1+1-4*(k1>3)
  b2=k2
  rvdc=machine.ADC(26).read_u16()
  if ttt==t:
    machine.lightsleep(100)
  if ttt!=t:
    ttt=t
    s=str(int((t/60-t//60)*60));m=str(int((t/3600-t//3600)*60));h=str(int((t/86400-t//86400)*24));d=str(t//86400);w=str((t//86400*7))    # Extrapolate seconds hours minutes and days from raw uptime seconds
    tt=("00"+h)[-2:]+("00"+m)[-2:]+("00"+s)[-2:]+("00"+d)[-2:]+"77" # compile the output buffer 
    for nn in range(8):
      n=int(tt[nn])
      machine.SPI(0,baudrate=32768,sck=machine.Pin(2),mosi=machine.Pin(3),miso=machine.Pin(4)).readinto(puter,int(ssebr[n*8:n*8+8],2))
      chrout=str(puter)[12]
      if chrout==chr(92):
        print(ord(chr(int("0x"+(str(puter)[14:16])))),"$",end="")
      if chrout!=chr(92):
        print(ord(str(puter)[12]),"@",end="")
    machine.Pin(0).value(0)    # low latched the data into the display
    machine.Pin(0).value(1)    # high latched the data into the display
    print("")
```